# Add [Authorize] attribute to web api method and now getting Authorization has been denied

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, authorization, axios, windows-authentication

I am needing to Add Windows Authentication to my Web API 2 app,  it is not core,  it is 4.6.1

> {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}

MyController:

```
[Authorize]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[RoutePrefix("api/SAI")]
```

web.config

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    .....
</system.web>
```

I thought `Postman` or `SoapUI` would be able to pass headers or user/password , but nothing seems to work.

Ultimately my end goal is for **React.JS app that uses Axios** (i could switch to fetch ) I want to authenticate with knowing what to even pass in??

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is add an [Authorize] attribute to the methods you want to protect optionally using the overload that accepts one or more role names that the calling user must be in.

Then what you'll have to implement is a way to ensure that authentication data of the caller is transformed into a Principal object. Setting the Principal is generally something you don't do yourself, but instead have the framework do for you.

If you do want to provide your own interface, you can using an authentication filter implementing the System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter interface.

Bascially implemention is required while we add this attribute.

You can use [Authorize] attribute at particular API method as well as at controller level. In case you put the [Authorize] attribute at controller level then you can use [AllowAnonymous] attribute for those API method which you want to access without authentication.

Comment: For Windows Authentication, how do I use the Authorize attribute?  should a box appear for me to enter user/password?   Should it be SSO .. all silent ?  How does it know my id is allowed?   Should I pass a token from React in the header?  what is standard?